# Question about index of critical points.

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, morse-theory

I don't really understand what index of a critical point is and I am trying to do a very simple example.  I was wondering if someone could help me figure out what the index of the critical point $(0,0)$ is of the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The index of a nondegenerate critical point is the dimension of the set of downward pointing directions at that point. In this case, everything is pointing upward, so the index is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

The index of a critical point of a real-valued function $f$ is the number of negative eigenvalues of the Hessian of $f$ at that critical point.

For your function, we have the following:
$$DF_{(x,y)} = \begin{pmatrix} 2x & 2y \end{pmatrix}.$$
Hence the only critical point of $f$ is $(0,0)$.

The Hessian of $f$ is
$$\mathrm{Hess}(f)(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
So at the critical point $(0,0)$, we have
$$\mathrm{Hess}(f)(0,0) = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix},$$
which clearly has eigenvalues $2$ and $2$, which are positive. Hence
$$\mathrm{ind}(f)(0,0) = 0.$$

In this example, the Hessian matrix turned out to be constant; in general you need to plug in the critical point in order to get a matrix with real number entries. Additionally, the Hessian here was already diagonal so we could read the eigenvalues immediately; in general we need to do the usual linear algebra to find the eigenvalues of the Hessian. Finally, in this example the function was defined on Euclidean space; in general one has a real-valued function on a smooth manifold and we need to use local coordinates to write out the Hessian.

Answer (score 2):

At a non-degenerate critical point, the tangent plane to $z = f(x, y)$ is horizontal.  It's a $2$-dimensional vector space, so there are $2$ independent directions one could travel an infinitesimal distance away from the critical point.  How many of those bend downward?

This is measured by the number of negative eigenvalues of the Hessian
$$
H(f) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial y}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

In your example,
$$
H(f) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$ occurs (with multiplicity $2$), so there are $0$ negative eigenvalues.  This means that the critical point has index $0$.

Geometrically, when you view $z = f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ as the paraboloid surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the Morse function is just projection onto the $z$-coordinate.  The critical point of degree zero corresponds to the introduction of the $0$-dimensional disk (a point) in the iterative construction of (a homotopy equivalent representative of) the surface.  Since the paraboloid is contractible, this is the end of the story.

Answer (score 1):

As [Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/386960/59510) and another have already stated, your critical point is a minimum and thus has an index of zero.

To provide another example, let's consider the function $g(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$

For this alternative function, we have the following:
$$DF_{(x,y)} = \begin{pmatrix} 2x & -2y \end{pmatrix}.$$

Hence the only critical point of $g$ is, like $f$ at $(0,0)$.

The Hessian of $g$ is
$$\mathrm{Hess}(g)(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
So at the critical point $(0,0)$, we have
$$\mathrm{Hess}(g)(0,0) = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix},$$
which clearly has eigenvalues $2$ and $-2$. Hence
$$\mathrm{ind}(g)(0,0) = 1$$

This 2d function has an index of 1. Although all the derivatives are zero, we are not at a maximum or a minimum. Instead we can move along the $x$ direction to increase the value of the function and move along the $y$ direction to decrease the value of the function.

As [was noted in the comments on the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386950/question-about-index-of-critical-points#comment827933_386950), the index is the number of principle directions in which we can move to decrease the value of the function. For this function, there is one principle direction (the y direction) in which we can move, so the index of the function is one.

In a space with $n$ dimensions, the index is an integer in the range [0, $n$]. For example, in 10 dimensional space, a saddle point could have index 8 (meaning there are eight dimensions along which the function will decrease) or dimension 2 (meaning that the function *increases* along eight dimensions).  A quick skim through [this paper about training neural networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.0233.pdf) suggests that critical points with lower indexes are closer to the minima of a function -- which would make sense, since such points would have fewer directions you could go down towards a minimum.

As a higher-dimensional example, the function

$$f(x,y,z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g) = - x^2 - y^2 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + g^2 + h^2$$

has index 2. Although this function does NOT have any local minima, if we imagine this function as a local approximation to a larger function that does, we can imagine the dimensions x and y having directions we could move to get closer to a local minimum -- feels likely that this point is closer to a local minimum than an index eight critical point!

Much of the text of this answer is directly copied from [Henry's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/386960/59510), adapting it to the example function $g(x,y)$ used in this answer.